# GoogleApiClient cannot connect in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, google-api-client

I failed to connect google map Api client from a while. Even the object returns  not null but still it cannot connect.
I've also mentioned permissions in manifest

Below is my code

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
}

         protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(mLocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
   // 

LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,new LocationCallback());
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
```

My gradle dependencies look like this

```
 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am new to google maps projects and know less about it. Kindly help me if any one have the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: "Can't connect" – is there an error code?

Comment: check if your country is banned in google or not 
also check if these two lines exist in manifest file 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: and add a log in onMapReady()

Comment: call buildGoogleApiClient(); in onCreate()

Comment: no error code sir. just isConnected() returns false. Can any problem occur with deprecated API :LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this) ?? @TheWanderer

Comment: Are you requesting the user grant location permissions at runtime? This needs to be done on Marshmallow and later.

Comment: @puya ars yes i've added permissions and onMapReady() calls successfully. the problem arise from buildGoogleApiClient() method

Comment: @TheWanderer yes i've added. location permissions needed for connecting map API?

Comment: Starting with Android Marshmallow, just putting the needed permissions in the manifest is no longer enough. See [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: @TheWanderer  will it due to using deprecated APi class "LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)" in onConnected() method??

Comment: I don't know. But I'm pretty sure that you aren't requesting the location permission at runtime, like you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by implementing `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` in the public class that I used. You probably haven't done that and that's required for it to connect to the API.